# R: sum elements in a matrix up to threshold

Tags: r

I have a matrix of values with thousands of rows and a couple dozen columns. For a given row, $$R_0$$, I'd like to find all other complementary rows. A complementary row is defined as:

1. if given row has a non-zero value for a column, then the complement must have a zero value for that column
2. the sum of the elements of a given row and its complements must be less than 1.0

To illustrate, here is a toy matrix:

```
     [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0         0        0         0.1816416 0         0.1796779
[2,] 0.1889351 0        0         0         0         0        
[3,] 0         0        0.1539683 0         0         0.1983812
[4,] 0         0.155489 0.1869410 0         0         0        
[5,] 0         0        0         0         0.1739382 0
```

For row 1, there are values for columns 4 and 6. A complementary row must have "0" for columns 4 and 6.

I don't know what data structure my desired output should be. But I know the output should tell me:

- row 1 has the following complementary rows: 2, 3, 5
- row 2 has the following complementary rows: 1, 3, 4, 5
- row 3 has the following complementary rows: 2, 5
- row 4 has the following complementary rows: 1, 2, 5
- row 5 has the following complementary rows: 1, 2, 3, 4

Perhaps a list of lists? I.e.:

```
[1: 2, 3, 5;
 2: 1, 3, 4, 5;
 3: 2, 5;
 4: 1, 2, 5;
 5: 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But I'm open to other data structures.

The following code generates the toy matrix above.

```
set.seed(1)
a = runif(n=30, min=0, max=0.2)
a[a<0.15] = 0
A = matrix(a,              # the data elements 
           nrow=5,         # number of rows 
           ncol=6,         # number of columns 
           byrow = TRUE)   # fill matrix by rows
```

Is there a package or clever way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please provide your expected output for your sample matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a function to check if the combination of two rows is a compliment

```
check_compliment <- function(x, y) {
  all(A[y, A[x,] != 0] == 0) & sum(c(A[x, ], A[y, ])) < 1
}
```

Here, we subset row `y` for columns where `x` is not 0 and check if `all` of them are 0. Also check if `sum` of `x` and `y` rows is less than 1.

Apply this function for every combination using `outer`

```
sapply(data.frame(outer(1:nrow(A), 1:nrow(A), Vectorize(check_compliment))), which)

#$X1
#[1] 2 4 5

#$X2
#[1] 1 3 4 5

#$X3
#[1] 2 5

#$X4
#[1] 1 2 5

#$X5
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

`outer` step gives us `TRUE`/`FALSE` value for every combination of a row with every other row indicating if it is a compliment

```
outer(1:nrow(A), 1:nrow(A), Vectorize(check_compliment))
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#[2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

We convert this to data frame and use `which` to get indices for every column.

Comment: Mind helping answer a related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578186/r-dplyr-function-that-quickly-builds-list-of-complementary-rows-based-on-condi?noredirect=1#comment97855270_55578186