# R, dplyr: Function that quickly builds list of complementary rows based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set of ~80,000 rows by 26 columns. The rows correspond to "SKUs" or unique IDs for robot building sets. The columns correspond to 26 different robot parts. A cell contains a part's contribution towards building a whole robot. The sum of a row's proportion may not sum to 1.0 since a building set won't always have 100% of the parts needed to build a whole robot.

The main goal is to build a function that accepts a SKU as input and outputs a list of complementary SKUs. A complementary row is defined as:

1. if given row has a non-zero value for a column, then the complement must have a zero value for that column.

The goal is to find all possible sets of SKUs that complement a given SKU such that a whole robot can be built. Additionally, it is important to see the weighted revenue per robot ("`weightedPrice`") for this "Frankenstein" set of SKUs. It is also nice to show how the `weightedPrice` changes with the addition of each complementary SKU.

A minimum working, toy example (MWE):

```
set.seed(1)
a = runif(n=60, min=0, max=0.2)
a[a<0.12] = 0
n = 10
A = as.data.frame(matrix(a,              
                         nrow=n,         
                         ncol=6,         
                         byrow = TRUE))
A$rowTally <- rowSums(A != 0)
A$sku <- seq(from = 1, to = n)
A$totalDollarSales <- runif(n=n, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6)
A$totalUnitSales <- runif(n=n, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6)
names(A) <- c("p1_prop", "p2_prop", "p3_prop", "p4_prop", "p5_prop", "p6_prop", "rowTally", "sku", "totalDollarSales", "totalUnitSales")
A <- A[c("sku", "p1_prop", "p2_prop", "p3_prop", "p4_prop", "p5_prop", "p6_prop", "rowTally", "totalDollarSales", "totalUnitSales")]
A$dollarsPerRobot <- A$totalDollarSales/A$totalUnitSales
A

   sku   p1_prop   p2_prop   p3_prop   p4_prop   p5_prop   p6_prop rowTally
1    1 0         0         0         0.1816416 0         0.1796779        2
2    2 0.1889351 0.1321596 0.1258228 0         0         0                3
3    3 0.1374046 0         0.1539683 0         0.1435237 0.1983812        4
4    4 0         0.1554890 0.1869410 0         0.1303348 0                3
5    5 0         0         0         0         0.1739382 0                1
6    6 0         0         0         0         0.1654747 0.1336933        2
7    7 0.1588480 0         0.1447422 0         0.1641893 0.1294120        4
8    8 0.1565866 0         0         0.1578712 0         0                2
9    9 0.1464627 0.1385463 0         0.1722419 0         0                3
10  10 0         0         0         0         0.1324010 0                1
   totalDollarSales totalUnitSales dollarsPerRobot
1         912884.64       339139.0       2.6917711
2         293674.01       839456.4       0.3498383
3         459119.82       346748.8       1.3240703
4         332461.43       333841.6       0.9958659
5         650905.38       476403.6       1.3662898
6         258090.98       892209.1       0.2892718
7         478597.39       864353.0       0.5537059
8         766334.04       390050.5       1.9647044
9          84338.49       777343.0       0.1084959
10        875333.80       960621.9       0.9112157
```

I'm trying to write a function:

```
def frankensteinRobot(df, sku, skuRowTally):
    1. find another SKU in dataframe, df.
       - must have non-overlapping parts with existing SKU set
       - rowTally <= skuRowTally (want to find small SKUs to add)
       - must be relatively same number of totalUnitSales
    2. append new SKU to list, and take mininum of totalUnitSales. 
    3. Calculate the weighted, per robot price
       dollarsPerRobotSKU_1*(1/length(SKU_list))+...+dollarsPerRobotSKU_n*(1/length(SKU_list)) 
       and append to the end of a list so we can track profitability with each additional SKU.
    4. repeat steps 1, 2 & 3.
```

I've only been able to figure out how to find the **next** complementary SKU, but not the full set of SKUs:

```
A_candidates <- sapply(data.frame(outer(1:nrow(A), 1:nrow(A), Vectorize(check_compliment))), which)
```

Example input:

```
frankensteinRobot(df = A, sku = 5, skuRowTally = 3)
```

Example output (note that because my MWE only has 10 rows, the example output lists only have 2 elements, but in actually they will be longer. Also, I'm unsure as to what data structure is appropriate. Maybe a dataframe where 1 column is a list?):

```
[list of SKUs]; [propSum]; [maxLb]; [list of weightedPrice]

[5, 2]; [propSum=0.6208557]; [maxLb=476403.6]; [0.8580641)
[5, 8]; [propSum=0.488396]; [maxLb=390050.5]; [1.665497]
[5, 9]; [propSum=0.6311891]; [maxLb=476403.6]; [0.7373929]
```

Example input:

```
frankensteinRobot(df = A, sku = 6, skuRowTally = 2)
```

Example output:

```
[6, 8]; [propSum=0.6136258]; [maxLb=390050.5]; [1.126988]
```

Comment: Can you describe your goal in words in addition to your algorithm? There might be a much better way to do it...

Comment: What exactly is a good compliment? If there is some overlap, is that ok? Should all the zero parts be represented in the complimentary SKU, or only some of them is still good?

Comment: @iod a good compliment has no overlap with the existing SKU set. Initially, the SKU set has 1 element, the original input SKU. Not all of the zero parts needs to be represented in the next complimentary SKU, since we iteratively add more SKUs.

Comment: @Gregor I added a description of my goal, thanks

Comment: Are you ultimately looking for the best combination, or do you really need all possible combinations? It might be a very long list for your full data.

Comment: Why do you `(want to find small SKUs to add)`? It's not clear to me how that or the totalUnitSales factor into the evaluation of potential solutions.

Comment: Must the SKU sets achieve a complete robot? I.e should combinations of non-overlapping SKUs obtain non-zero values in all p1 - p26 columns?  Also, as at @JonSpring says why is it necessary? `rowTally <= skuRowTally (want to find small SKUs to add)` ? if you start with an SKU with a small number of parts, if there's a perfectly complimentary SKU with a larger number of parts why exclude it?

Comment: @JonSpring I need all possible combinations. The definition of the "best" combination changes depending on the criteria, but it is easy for me to sort and filter the results on my own (i.e. descending weightedPrice). Yes, I expect the output to be a long list of lists of combinations.

Comment: @Roasty247 Great question. I want to build a robot from "small SKUs" because it is easy to manually find a big SKU, with values for p1-p25, and find another SKU with just p26. It is much harder to find all combinations of small SKUs that would build a whole robot. As for whether the robot must be complete or not, I think it would be good to have an optional flag: "complete = TRUE" or "complete = FALSE" which determines whether a complete robot must be assembled.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last two comments. If you are seeking all possible combinations, I'm not sure why you would prefer the ones that are easier to find vs. the ones that are hard to find. And if you're seeking all possible combinations, even limiting to just "adding complementary skus," I'd think with 80k rows to choose from would lead to gazillions of combinations, even with only combinations of a low number of skus. With 26 parts, almost every remaining row will be complimentary to the first row you start with, which is already around 80k^2 combinations, or over 6 billion.

Comment: @JonSpring *All possible combinations after filtering the dataset by `rowTally<=skuRowTally`. Also, I am able to filter the 80K rows of the original dataset down to a subset of about 1-2K rows.

Comment: I understand that you would want to change the final criteria, but a function which  returns a list of combinations fulfilling every potential criteria (min/max of totalDollarSales, totalUnitSales, dollarsPerRobot, rowTally,etc.), even if the number of them would be >10, instead of all potential combinations of SKU would be much much faster, especially in the case of 26 columns. Consider this.

Comment: Could you give us max and limit values of `a` (0.2, 0.12 for 6 parts) for the case of 26 parts?

Comment: I think @JonSpring is right that this is going to become intractable. The number of iterations is going to be at least 80,000! because for each SKU you have to check all of the other SKUs. They may not be added to the list or valid because they violate some condition, but you still have to check them to learn that.

Comment: @GrzegorzSionkowski they are proportions, so the max value for single one of the 26 parts is 1.0

Comment: @Wil I don't think that's right. I can just limit the input size for this function to 2K rows or something after filtering based on other conditions

Comment: @user2205916 but wouldn’t each of those 2k have to check each of the other 79,999?

Comment: @user2205916 Are you just trying to maximize the weighted revenue by building complete robots? i.e. getting small number of parts from cheaper compliments is in general better?

Answer (score 3):

**Final Edit**: This solution relies on data.table and could use a loop at the end. Still, you could keep on copying and pasting to make it work. The solution relies mainly on this blazingly quick solution:

```
  search_dt <- dt[sku1 == searchSKU]
  current_parts <- names(search_dt[, .SD, .SDcols = part_names])[which(search_dt[, .SD, .SDcols = part_names]>0)]

  steal_dt <- dt[rowTally <= searchRowTally]

#returns SKUs which are 0 for the parts we already have
  steal_dt <- steal_dt[steal_dt[, j = rowSums(.SD) == 0, .SDcols = current_parts]]

  franken_rob <- cbind(search_dt, steal_dt)
```

I'm still uncertain on some of the criteria. I assume that as FrankenBot is assembled, each successive SKU can't be in the previous parts. In other words, SKU3 doesn't have any parts in common with SKU1 and SKU2.

Solution output [I edited it one more time...]{and yet another...}:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 8
    sku1  sku2  sku3 propSums Parts Robots dollarsPerRobot totalUnitSales
   <int> <int> <int>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     1     2     5    0.982     6      3           1.47         339139.
 2     1     2    10    0.941     6      3           1.32         339139.
 3     1     4    NA    0.834     5      2           1.84         333842.
 4     1     5    NA    0.535     3      2           2.03         339139.
 5     1    10    NA    0.494     3      2           1.80         339139.
 6     2     5    NA    0.621     4      2           0.858        476404.
 7     2     6    NA    0.746     5      2           0.320        839456.
 8     2    10    NA    0.579     4      2           0.631        839456.
 9     4     8    NA    0.787     5      2           1.48         333842.
10     5     8    NA    0.488     3      2           1.67         390051.
11     5     9    NA    0.631     4      2           0.737        476404.
12     6     8    NA    0.614     4      2           1.13         390051.
13     6     9    NA    0.756     5      2           0.199        777343.
14     8    10    NA    0.447     3      2           1.44         390051.
15     9    10    NA    0.590     4      2           0.510        777343.
```

solution code:

```
library(data.table)
# generate data -----------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(1)
n = 10
cols = 6 #added
part_names =  paste0('p', c(1:cols), '_prop')

a = runif(n* cols, min=0, max=0.2)
a[a<0.12] = 0

A <- data.table(matrix(a, nrow=n, ncol=cols,byrow = TRUE))
A[, `:=`(rowTally1 = rowSums(.SD != 0),
         sku1 = .I
         ,totalDollarSales1 = runif(n=n, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6)
         ,totalUnitSales1 =  runif(n=n, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6))]

A[, dollarsPerRobot1:=totalDollarSales1/totalUnitSales1]

setnames(A, c(paste0('V',1:cols)), part_names)
setcolorder(A, 'sku1')

non_part_names<- setdiff(names(A), c('sku1',part_names))
non_part_names<- stringr::str_sub(non_part_names, 1, -2)

search_fun <- function (search_dt, steal_dt, searchSKU, b_loop = FALSE, sale_range = NULL) {

  sku_count<- length(grep('sku', names(search_dt)))
  skus <- paste0('sku', 1:(sku_count+1))

  non_parts<- paste0(non_part_names, rep(1:(sku_count+1), each = length(non_part_names)))

  blank_table <- setnames(data.table(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(search_dt) + 1 + length(non_part_names))),c(skus,part_names, non_parts))

  if (length(searchSKU) != sku_count) {
    stop('not enough SKUs to go around')
  } 

  for (i in 1:length(searchSKU)) {
    search_dt <- search_dt[get(paste0('sku', i)) == searchSKU[i]]
  }
  current_parts <- names(search_dt[, .SD, .SDcols = part_names])[which(search_dt[, .SD, .SDcols = part_names]>0)]
  search_dt[, (setdiff(part_names, current_parts)) := NULL, ]

  # Could be made faster if sku1s were filtered out to whichever ones were is sku.N 
  # Right now it still looks through skus that may have already been filtered out.

  if (!is.null(sale_range)) {
    if (length(sale_range) != 2) {
      warning('Sale range needs to be length two with sale_range[1] = lower range and sale_range[2] = upper range')
    } else {
    steal_dt <- steal_dt[between(totalUnitSales1, sale_range[1] * search_dt$totalUnitSales1, search_dt$totalUnitSales1 * sale_range[2])]
    }
  }


  if (b_loop) {
    steal_dt <- steal_dt[sku1 > searchSKU[sku_count]]
  }

  steal_dt <- steal_dt[steal_dt[, j = rowSums(.SD) == 0, .SDcols = current_parts]]
  if (nrow(steal_dt) == 0) {
    return(blank_table)
  }

  steal_dt[, (current_parts) := NULL]
  setnames(steal_dt,
           c('sku1', paste0(non_part_names, '1')) ,
           c(paste0('sku',sku_count+1),
             paste0(non_part_names, sku_count+1))
  )

  franken_rob <- cbind(search_dt, steal_dt)
  setcolorder(franken_rob, c(skus, part_names))
  return(franken_rob)

}

searchRowTally <- 3
dt_search <- A

#this is done outside the function because there can be a lot of looping otherwise
dt_steal <- dt_search[rowTally1 <= searchRowTally]

#Near-instant with 80,000 rows and 26 columns
search_fun(dt_search, dt_steal, dt_search$sku1[5])
search_fun(dt_search, dt_steal, dt_search$sku1[5], b_loop = TRUE)
search_fun(dt_search, dt_steal, dt_search$sku1[5], sale_range = c(0.8, 1.2))
search_fun(dt_search, dt_steal, dt_search$sku1[5], b_loop = TRUE, sale_range = c(0.8, 1.2))

#Not doable with 80,000 rows, but still nice
rbindlist(lapply(1:(n-1), function (i) search_fun(dt_search, dt_steal, dt_search$sku1[i], b_loop = TRUE)))
rbindlist(lapply(1:(n-1), function (i) search_fun(dt_search, dt_steal, dt_search$sku1[i], b_loop = TRUE, sale_range = c(0.8, 1.2))))

#much more likely that the first regression would be a single value
# frank_1 <- search_fun(dt_search, dt_steal, dt_search$sku1[5], FALSE)
frank_1 <-  rbindlist(lapply(1:(n-1), function (i) search_fun(dt_search, dt_steal, dt_search$sku1[i],  TRUE)))

#This takes every n-1 of each sku1 group. 
frank_2 <- frank_1[frank_1[, head(.I, -1), by = sku1]$V1]
# frank_2 <- frank_1[, j = if(.N!=1) .SD, by = sku1]
dt_steal2 <- dt_steal[sku1 %in% base::unique(frank_1$sku2)]

frank_2 = rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(frank_2), function (i) search_fun(frank_2, dt_steal2, melt(frank_2[i, .SD, .SDcols = grep('sku', names(frank_2))])[[2]],  TRUE)))

frank_3 <- frank_2[frank_2[, head(.I, -1), by = sku2]$V1]
dt_steal3 <- dt_steal2[sku1 %in% base::unique(frank_2$sku3)]

frank_3 = rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(frank_3), function (i) search_fun(frank_3, dt_steal3, melt(frank_3[i, .SD, .SDcols = grep('sku', names(frank_3))])[[2]],  TRUE)))


# start combindine our lists

franken_rob <- frank_1[!frank_2, on = c('sku1', 'sku2')]
franken_rob[, j= sku3:= integer()]
setcolorder(franken_rob, c('sku1','sku2','sku3'))

franken_rob <- rbind(frank_2, franken_rob, fill = TRUE)
#do above for frank_n times)

franken_rob[, `:=`(propSums=rowSums(.SD),
                   Parts = rowSums(.SD > 0))
            , .SDcols = part_names]

franken_rob[, Robots:= rowSums(.SD > 0, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = grep('sku', names(franken_rob))]
franken_rob[, dollarsPerRobot := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE) / Robots, .SDcols = grep ('dollarsPerRobot', names(franken_rob))]
franken_rob[, totalUnitSales := do.call(pmin,  c(.SD, list(na.rm = TRUE))), .SDcols = grep('totalUnitSales', names(franken_rob))]

franken_rob[, (part_names) := NULL]
franken_rob

tibble::as_tibble(franken_rob[, c(1:3, 16, 17, 18, 19,20)])
```

**Edit**: I don't have enough rep to comment - when trying the data.table solution with 80,000 rows and 26 columns, it tries to allocate a 2.3 GB vector when `rowTally <= 13`. However, when I change that to 3, it makes 1.1 million rows and filters down to 0.3 million rows. This is super cartesian.

**Original**: Here is a dplyr solution that seems to work with 80,000 rows and 26 columns. The trick was to figure out which columns had a non-zero result for the subset sku. With those columns, I went back to the original df and filtered.

There's also a line commented out for the unitSales being in some range.

```
set.seed(1)
n = 10
cols = 6 #added

part_names =  paste0('p', c(1:cols), '_prop') #added
a = runif(n * cols, min=0, max=0.2) #changed from n to n * cols
a[a<0.12] = 0

A = as.data.frame(matrix(a,              
                         nrow=n,         
                         ncol=cols,  #changed to cols      
                         byrow = TRUE))
A$rowTally <- rowSums(A != 0)
A$sku <- seq(from = 1, to = n)
A$totalDollarSales <- runif(n=n, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6)
A$totalUnitSales <- runif(n=n, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6)
names(A) <- c(part_names, "rowTally", "sku", "totalDollarSales", "totalUnitSales")
A <- A[c("sku", part_names, "rowTally", "totalDollarSales", "totalUnitSales")]
A$dollarsPerRobot <- A$totalDollarSales/A$totalUnitSales


library(dplyr)

df <- as_tibble(A)%>%
  mutate(propSum = rowSums(.[, part_names]))

search_sku <- 5
skuRowTally <- 3

search_df <- df%>%
  filter(sku == search_sku)

current_parts <- search_df%>%
  select(part_names)%>%
  select_if(~sum(.)> 0)%>%
  names()

non_current_parts <- search_df%>%
  select(part_names)%>%
  select_if(~sum(.) == 0)%>%
  names()

df%>%
  filter(rowTally <= skuRowTally,
         sku != search_sku
         # , between(totalUnitSales, 0.7 * search_df$totalUnitSales, 1.3 * search_df$totalUnitSales)
         )%>%
  filter_at(vars(current_parts), all_vars(. == 0))%>%
  filter_at(vars(non_current_parts), any_vars(. != 0))%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  transmute(sku_search = search_sku,
            sku = sku,
            propSum = propSum + search_df$propSum,
            minLB = min(totalUnitSales, search_df$totalUnitSales),
            weightedPrice = (dollarsPerRobot + search_df$dollarsPerRobot) / 2,
            total_parts = rowTally + search_df$rowTally,
            complete_robot = if_else(total_parts == cols, 'COMPLETE', 'incomplete')
  )%>%
  ungroup()


frankensteinRobot <- function (df, sku1, skuTally) {
  # df <- as_tibble(df)%>%
  #   mutate(propSum = rowSums(.[, part_names]))


#part_name and cols would also need to be passed to make this
#completely stand alone.  

  search_sku <- sku1
  skuRowTally <- skuTally

  search_df <- df%>%
    filter(sku == search_sku)

  current_parts <- search_df%>%
    select(part_names)%>%
    select_if(~sum(.)> 0)%>%
    names()

  non_current_parts <- search_df%>%
    select(part_names)%>%
    select_if(~sum(.) == 0)%>%
    names()

  df%>%
    filter(rowTally <= skuRowTally,
           sku > search_sku
           # , between(totalUnitSales, 0.7 * search_df$totalUnitSales, 1.3 * search_df$totalUnitSales)
    )%>%
    filter_at(vars(current_parts), all_vars(. == 0))%>%
    filter_at(vars(non_current_parts), any_vars(. != 0))%>%
    rowwise()%>%
    transmute(sku_search = search_sku,
              sku = sku,
              propSum = propSum + search_df$propSum,
              minLB = min(totalUnitSales, search_df$totalUnitSales),
              weightedPrice = (dollarsPerRobot + search_df$dollarsPerRobot) / 2,
              total_parts = rowTally + search_df$rowTally,
              complete_robot = if_else(total_parts == cols, 'COMPLETE', 'incomplete')
    )%>%
    ungroup()
}

A<- as_tibble(A)%>%
  mutate(propSum = rowSums(.[, part_names]))

#I tried running 1:n with 80,000 rows. It wasn't pretty

bind_rows(lapply(1:n, function(x) frankensteinRobot(A, x, 3)))
```

edit: here's an attempt at a data.table solution. It's got some similarities but instead of doing it as a loop, it's one go around. If I could figure out how to get your main condition of no matching parts, it probably wouldn't be too shabby. Right now the bottleneck is memory and this as I can't get intersect to work on my list of lists.

```
results[
apply(results[, .(current_parts, rbt_missing_curr_parts)], 1, function(x) length(intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]))==0)
]
```

Main code:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(A)

dt[
  ,j = `:=`(propSum = rowSums(.SD),
           current_parts = list(which(.SD > 0)),
           missing_parts = list(which(.SD == 0)))
  ,.SDcols = part_names,
  by = sku]

#could subset here as dt[1:100, ...] which would allow bigger datasets
dt_missing_parts <- dt[, .( sku, propSum, current_parts, rowTally, missing_parts, dollarsPerRobot, up_range = 1.3 *totalUnitSales, low_range = 0.7 * totalUnitSales)]

results<- dt_missing_parts[dt[rowTally <= round(cols / 2)],
                 j = .(i.sku, sku,
                       propSum = propSum + i.propSum, 
                       dollarsPerRobot = (dollarsPerRobot + i.dollarsPerRobot) / 2,
                       totalUnitSales = pmin(totalUnitSales, i.totalUnitSales),
                       rbt_missing_curr_parts = i.current_parts, 
                       current_parts,
                       rpt_missing_missing_parts= i.missing_parts,
                       missing_parts,
                       total_parts = rowTally + i.rowTally),
                 on = .(sku > sku
                        #more conditions would be great
                        # ,low_range < totalUnitSales
                        # ,up_range > totalUnitSales
                        ),
                 allow.cartesian = TRUE,
                 nomatch = 0L,
                 by = .I
                 ]
results
results[
apply(results[, .(current_parts, rbt_missing_curr_parts)], 1, function(x) length(intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]))==0)
]
```

Comment: I like this solution. I was able to make it work for my current data set with minimal editing. I like the lists of missing parts, current parts, etc. However, it seems like your code only builds sets of two complementary SKUs whereas I would need a solution builds sets that maximize total_parts, which may include adding more SKUs.

Comment: I changed it to allow regression to keep looping through sku1, sku2, ..., sku3. I didn't have time to finish to make the exact column set, but that should be trivial now.

Comment: I added some more options in the final edit response. Still, this is cartesian and recursive. With this data size, the user would need to make some choices instead of finding all combinations as you'll quickly run out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

So my coding vocabulary is not very broad, but I thought I would have a go with what I know, and I managed to do this with a small dataset (slightly larger than your OP example). It seems to work and produces something very close to the desired output. I tried to proof it with a larger dataset, not even close to 80,000 x 26, and it very quickly ground to a halt. Anyone more experienced with coding than me could probably see that this was not a good approach given the size of the dataset. I don't recommend using this on a larger dataset, but given that I spent time on it, that it provisionally works, and that perhaps it could be useful as inspiration to substitute faster functions in and achieve a better result - I thought I would post it anyway. It did produce an error message at one step, I don't know why, but actually worked fine still. I couldn't get it into a function either because of the error but the script did the job.

```
# (df = A, SKU = 5, skuRowTally =  26)    
a = runif(n=120, min=0, max=0.2)
a[a<0.12] = 0
n = 20
A = as.data.frame(matrix(a,              
                         nrow=n,         
                         ncol=6,         
                         byrow = TRUE))
A$rowTally <- rowSums(A != 0)
A$sku <- seq(from = 1, to = n)
A$totalDollarSales <- runif(n=n, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6)
A$totalUnitSales <- runif(n=n, min=1*10^2, max=1*10^6)
names(A) <- c("p1_prop", "p2_prop", "p3_prop", "p4_prop", "p5_prop", "p6_prop", "rowTally", "sku", "totalDollarSales", "totalUnitSales")
A <- A[c("sku", "p1_prop", "p2_prop", "p3_prop", "p4_prop", "p5_prop", "p6_prop", "rowTally", "totalDollarSales", "totalUnitSales")]
A$dollarsPerRobot <- A$totalDollarSales/A$totalUnitSales


Output <- unique(rbind(A[which(A$sku == 5),],A[which(A$rowTally <= 26),])) # change df, SKU and skuRowTally here

for(i in 2:7) { #change 2:7 to your columns with parts props
  if(Output[which(Output$sku == 5),][i] !=  0) { # change SKU here
    Output <- Output[which(Output[,i] == 0),]
    Output <- rbind(A[which(A$sku == 5),],Output) # change SKU here
  }
}

Sets <- vector('list', nrow(Output)) 
head_list <- paste(rep("V",nrow(Output)),seq(1:nrow(Output)),sep="")
for(i in 2:nrow(Output)){
  Sets[[i]] <- as.data.frame(t(combn(Output$sku,i)))
  Sets[[i]] <- Sets[[i]][which(Sets[[i]][,1]==5),] # change SKU here
}

for(i in 2:length(Sets)){
  for(j in min(which(seq(1,length(head_list))>i),na.rm = TRUE):max(which(seq(1,length(head_list))>i),na.rm=TRUE)){
    Sets[[i]][,head_list[j]]<-NA
  }
}

Sets <- do.call(rbind,Sets)

Binary.Output <- Output

for(i in 2:7){ #change 2:7 to your columns with parts props
  Binary.Output[,i] <- ifelse(Binary.Output[,i] == 0,0,1)
}

for(i in 1:nrow(Sets)){
  Sets$Good.Combo[i] <-
    ifelse(any(apply(Binary.Output[which(Binary.Output$sku %in% Sets[i,1:nrow(Output)]),], MARGIN = 2, sum)[2:7] > 1),"BAD","GOOD") #change 2:7 to your columns with parts props
}

Sets <- Sets[which(Sets$Good.Combo == "GOOD"),]

for(i in 1:nrow(Sets)){
  Sets$Total.Parts[i] <-
    sum(Binary.Output[which(Binary.Output$sku %in% Sets[i,1:nrow(Binary.Output)]),][2:7]) #change 2:7 to your columns with parts props
  Sets$Complete[i] <- 
    ifelse(Sets$Total.Parts[i]< ncol(Output[,2:7]), "INCOMPLETE", "COMPLETE")
  Sets$MaxLb[i] <-
    min(Output[which(Output$sku %in% Sets[i,1:nrow(Output)]),"totalDollarSales"],na.rm = TRUE)
  Sets$Prop.Sum[i] <-
    sum(Output[which(Output$sku %in% Sets[i,1:nrow(Output)]),2:7])

}

for(i in 1:nrow(Sets)) {
  DPR <- c(1:length(c(t(Sets[i,1:nrow(Output)]))[which(!is.na(c(t(Sets[i,1:nrow(Output)]))))]))
  for (j in 1:length(DPR))  { 
    DPR[j] <- Output[which(Output$sku %in% Sets[i,1:nrow(Output)]),"dollarsPerRobot"][j]*1/length(DPR)
  }
  Sets$weightedPrice[i] <- sum(DPR)
}

print(Sets)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 Good.Combo Total.Parts   Complete    MaxLb  Prop.Sum weightedPrice
1  5  4 NA NA NA       GOOD           4 INCOMPLETE 82485.02 0.6324902     2.6031580
2  5  7 NA NA NA       GOOD           5 INCOMPLETE 82485.02 0.8323490    13.2757958
3  5  9 NA NA NA       GOOD           4 INCOMPLETE 82485.02 0.6152630     1.4411304
4  5 10 NA NA NA       GOOD           4 INCOMPLETE 82485.02 0.6117570     0.5724854
5  5  4  7 NA NA       GOOD           6   COMPLETE 82485.02 0.9854523    10.5475486
6  5  4  9 NA NA       GOOD           5 INCOMPLETE 82485.02 0.7683664     2.6577717
7  5  4 10 NA NA       GOOD           5 INCOMPLETE 82485.02 0.7648603     2.0786750
```

Comment: I also added to this the combined parts provided by the set of SKUs `Total.Parts` and whether this made a complete robot or not `Complete`. `Good.Combo` indicates non-overlap between part of the SKUs, i.e they are complementary.

Comment: The parts that work make this approach seem promising, however I get an error: `Error in min(which(seq(1, length(head_list)) > i), na.rm = TRUE):max(which(seq(1,  : 
  result would be too long a vector`

Comment: I got the same error, but it still produced the desired output strangely? I wasn't sure what caused the error exactly or why it still worked even with the error?

Answer (score 1):

Does this function at least help reduce the number of combinations so you don't run into memory issues? I wanted to see if I could get:

> 1. if given row has a non-zero value for a column, then the complement must have a zero value for that column.

correct. If my function helps with reducing the data first then I will add more to the answer, else I will probably delete it. Let me know if I am totally misunderstanding the issue.

```
library(dplyr)
robot <- function(df=A,x=1,skuRowTally=NA){
#get list of prop variables
A2 <- A[,2:7]
#get each name
nms <- colnames(A2)
#turn data into indicators
Ax <- data.frame(sapply(nms, function(x){ifelse(A2[x] ==0,0,1)}))
#reattach id
Ax2 <- cbind(A['sku'],Ax)
#get SKU of interest
b <- Ax[x,]
#comparison data
A3 <- Ax[-x,]
#names where it is a non-0 value
nms2<-names(b)[which(b==1)]

#get each indicator where you have to remove rows
x1 <- sapply(nms2, function(x){which(Ax[,x] != b[,x])})
#find final comparaitors 
Ax3 <- Ax2[Reduce(intersect,x1),]
#join back to original data 
inner_join(A,select(Ax3,sku), by = 'sku') %>% 
          bind_rows(A[x,]) 

}

robot()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: added helped functions to allow iteration to complete solution**

Here's a dplyr/tidyr solution that breaks the problem into two main steps.

First, given a list of rows already being used, *what remaining rows are complements* with no overlapping skus? The `find_complements` function below does, outputting a table showing all the non-overlapping skus and how many new skus they would contribute. This can be joined to the original data if you want to use a particular rule to make a choice.

The other main part is picking the "next move." To help with this, the `select_top` function accepts a column name and finds the remaining sku with the highest number, using in this example the default column of `totalUnitSales`.

To complete the step, a convenience function called `sku_string_to_chr_string` takes the output of `select_top` and makes the new sku chain into a vector that can be fed back into step 1.

This string works automatically, in a legible and easily modified fashion, to build up a complete robot. It uses some cutting-and-pasting to repeat the process until it's done, but there's probably a simple way to automate that, too.

---

```
library(tidyverse)
find_complements <- function(test_skus) {
  A_test <- A %>%
      add_row(sku = 0) %>%    # Creates a blank row corresponding to the 
                              #   case that no additional skus are added
      select(sku, p1_prop:p6_prop) %>%
      gather(part, val, -sku) %>%
      mutate(val = if_else(val > 0, TRUE, FALSE))

  A_test %>% 
    filter(sku %in% test_skus) %>%
    group_by(part) %>%
    summarize(val = any(val)) %>%
    mutate(sku = paste(test_skus, collapse = "_")) %>%
    right_join(A_test, by = "part") %>%
    mutate(eval = case_when(val.y & !val.x   ~ "Additive", # Adds part not already present
                            val.y & val.x    ~ "Overlap", # Uh-oh! Adds repeated part
                            val.x            ~ "Already", # Part already present, not doubled
                            TRUE             ~ "Both_missing")) %>% 
    mutate(sku_string = paste(sku.x, sku.y, sep = "_")) %>%
    count(sku_string, sku = sku.y, eval) %>%
    spread(eval, n, fill = 0) %>%
    filter(Overlap == 0)
}
```

Here's an output, showing how row one on its own (represented by the `1_0` row at the top) has two parts but is missing 4 parts. Adding sku 2 or 4 would add three more parts without overlap, leaving one part missing. Adding sku 5 or 10 would add one more part, with 3 parts still missing.

```
> find_complements(1)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  sku_string   sku Additive Already Both_missing Overlap
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1_0            0        0       2            4       0
2 1_10          10        1       2            3       0
3 1_2            2        3       2            1       0
4 1_4            4        3       2            1       0
5 1_5            5        1       2            3       0
```

We could pursue these strings further, for instance looking for additional complimentary strings given the use of skus 1 and 2. This shows that rows 5 or 10 would complete the robot, adding one more part to the five pre-existing, without causing any replication of parts.

```
> find_complements(c(1,2))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  sku_string   sku Additive Already Both_missing Overlap
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1_2_0          0        0       5            1       0
2 1_2_10        10        1       5            0       0
3 1_2_5          5        1       5            0       0
```

If other aspects of the new sku, like rowTally, bear on your choices, you could join the original table back on, and filter your choices with that too:

```
> find_complements(c(1,2)) %>%
+   left_join(A) %>%
+   filter(rowTally <= 2)
Joining, by = "sku"
# A tibble: 2 x 16
  sku_string   sku Additive Already Both_missing Overlap p1_prop p2_prop p3_prop
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1_2_10        10        1       5            0       0       0       0       0
2 1_2_5          5        1       5            0       0       0       0       0
# … with 7 more variables: p4_prop <dbl>, p5_prop <dbl>, p6_prop <dbl>,
#   rowTally <dbl>, totalDollarSales <dbl>, totalUnitSales <dbl>,
#   dollarsPerRobot <dbl>
```

**Edit: Here are two helper functions which take the output of one `find_complements`, pick the complement with highest `totalUnitSales` (or another variable of choosing), and create input to run `find_complements` again.**

```
# This function takes the output of `find_complements` and adds a column of choosing from the original table, defaulting to `totalUnitSales`, and picking the top one.
select_top <- function(df, top_col = "totalUnitSales") {
  df %>%
    left_join(A %>% select(sku, !!top_col)) %>%
    arrange(desc(!!rlang::sym(top_col))) %>%
    slice(1)
}

# This function takes the first cell and converts to a vector, so "10_2" becomes
#   vector   c(10, 2)
sku_string_to_chr_string <- function(df) {
  df[1,1] %>%
    str_split(pattern = "_") %>%
    flatten_chr()
}
```

Apply these iteratively and we get a complete answer, using rows 10, 2, and 1.

```
A %>%
  select_top() %>%
  sku_string_to_chr_string() %>%
  find_complements() %>%

  select_top() %>%
  sku_string_to_chr_string() %>%
  find_complements() %>%

  select_top() 

# A tibble: 1 x 7
  sku_string   sku Additive Already Both_missing Overlap totalUnitSales
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>
1 10_2_1         1        2       4            0       0        339139.
```

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring . I have tested your solution on my actual data and initial results look very promising. Will follow-up with more comments.

Comment: Can you either modify or write an extension that utilizes find_complements() such that it returns an entire set of SKUs that builds a whole robot? At each step of SKU selection, it can just pick the SKU with the most `totalUnitSales`.

Comment: Edited with complete solution, albeit with cut and paste to execute iteration. Anyone have suggestions on how to improve flow?

Answer (score 0):

Would this help ? I'm not sure if I got everything but this gets you all compatible combinations without doing a cartesian product nor duplication of pairs A/B B/A, it also does some aggregations that you can easily tweak.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- A
skuRowTally = 3

# we convert to matrix and transpose to be able to use vectorized
# operations later
m <- df %>% select(ends_with("prop")) %>% t()
colnames(m) <- 1:ncol(m)
m
#>                 1         2         3         4         5         6
#> p1_prop 0.0000000 0.1889351 0.1374046 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> p2_prop 0.0000000 0.1321596 0.0000000 0.1554890 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> p3_prop 0.0000000 0.1258228 0.1539683 0.1869410 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> p4_prop 0.1816416 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> p5_prop 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1435237 0.1303348 0.1739382 0.1654747
#> p6_prop 0.1796779 0.0000000 0.1983812 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1336933
#>                 7         8         9       10
#> p1_prop 0.1588480 0.1565866 0.1464627 0.000000
#> p2_prop 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1385463 0.000000
#> p3_prop 0.1447422 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000
#> p4_prop 0.0000000 0.1578712 0.1722419 0.000000
#> p5_prop 0.1641893 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.132401
#> p6_prop 0.1294120 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000
# subset potential complements
m_low <- m[, colSums(m) <= skuRowTally]
m_low
#>                 1         2         3         4         5         6
#> p1_prop 0.0000000 0.1889351 0.1374046 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> p2_prop 0.0000000 0.1321596 0.0000000 0.1554890 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> p3_prop 0.0000000 0.1258228 0.1539683 0.1869410 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> p4_prop 0.1816416 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> p5_prop 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1435237 0.1303348 0.1739382 0.1654747
#> p6_prop 0.1796779 0.0000000 0.1983812 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1336933
#>                 7         8         9       10
#> p1_prop 0.1588480 0.1565866 0.1464627 0.000000
#> p2_prop 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1385463 0.000000
#> p3_prop 0.1447422 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000
#> p4_prop 0.0000000 0.1578712 0.1722419 0.000000
#> p5_prop 0.1641893 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.132401
#> p6_prop 0.1294120 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000

# Then we extract all possible combinations, by looping, so we avoid a cartesian product
nc <- ncol(m)
candidates <- vector("list", nc-1) #%>% setNames(1:(nc-1))
for(i in seq_along(candidates)){
  if(any(rng <- colnames(m_low) > i)){
  candidates[[i]] <- names(which(!colSums(m[,i] & m_low[,rng, drop = FALSE])))
  }
}
candidates
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "2"  "4"  "5"  "10"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "5" "6"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> character(0)
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "8"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "8" "9"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "8" "9"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> character(0)
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> character(0)
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> NULL

# reformat and aggregate into output
candidates <- candidates[!!lengths(candidates)]
candidates_df <- 
  enframe(candidates[!!lengths(candidates)],"sku1","sku2") %>% 
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(sum = map2(
    sku1, sku2, ~summarize_all(df[c(.x, .y),-1], sum))) %>%
  mutate(delta = map2(
    sku1, sku2, ~summarize_all(df[c(.x, .y),9:11], ~abs(diff(.))))) %>%
  unnest(.sep = "_")
candidates_df
#> # A tibble: 11 x 15
#>     sku1 sku2  sum_p1_prop sum_p2_prop sum_p3_prop sum_p4_prop sum_p5_prop
#>    <int> <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1     1 2           0.189       0.132       0.126       0.182       0    
#>  2     1 4           0           0.155       0.187       0.182       0.130
#>  3     1 5           0           0           0           0.182       0.174
#>  4     1 10          0           0           0           0.182       0.132
#>  5     2 5           0.189       0.132       0.126       0           0.174
#>  6     2 6           0.189       0.132       0.126       0           0.165
#>  7     3 8           0.294       0           0.154       0.158       0.144
#>  8     4 8           0.157       0.155       0.187       0.158       0.130
#>  9     4 9           0.146       0.294       0.187       0.172       0.130
#> 10     5 8           0.157       0           0           0.158       0.174
#> 11     5 9           0.146       0.139       0           0.172       0.174
#> # ... with 8 more variables: sum_p6_prop <dbl>, sum_rowTally <dbl>,
#> #   sum_totalDollarSales <dbl>, sum_totalUnitSales <dbl>,
#> #   sum_dollarsPerRobot <dbl>, delta_totalDollarSales <dbl>,
#> #   delta_totalUnitSales <dbl>, delta_dollarsPerRobot <dbl>
```

Comment: This only finds the first element to add to the SKU set. There have to be iterative additions of complementary SKUs. And the set of complementary SKUs changes after each iteration since the set composition changes.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(Matrix)

# Matrix of non zeros
M <- as.matrix(A[, grepl("^p\\d+_prop$", names(A))]) != 0
M <- Matrix(M)
```

Function that iterates on combinations:

```r
combine_parts <- function(M1 = list(mat = M, sku = as.matrix(A$sku)), 
                          M2 = list(mat = M, sku = as.matrix(A$sku))) {
  # Combining the parts is a matrix product. Non overlapping means 0
  combinations <- M1$mat %*% t(M2$mat) == 0
  # Make it a sparse matrix to use the convenient summary() function
  combinations <- Matrix(combinations, sparse = TRUE)
  x <- summary(combinations)
  # This is to stop the computation when valid combinations are exhausted
  if (!nrow(x)) return(NULL)
  # Combine the SKUs separately
  sku <- apply(x, 1, function(.) c(M1$sku[.["i"], ], M2$sku[.["j"], ]))
  # Deduplicate SKUs
  sku <- t(apply(sku, 2, sort))
  # Whether a part is used by a new combination is a logical OR
  list(
    mat = t(apply(
      x[!duplicated(sku), ],
      MARGIN = 1, 
      function(.) M1$mat[.["i"], ] | M2$mat[.["j"], ]
    )),
    sku = sku[!duplicated(sku), ]
  )
}
```

Results:

```r
# Function combine_parts() is wrapped in a while loop to exhaust all combinations
x <- list(mat = M, sku = as.matrix(A$sku))
res <- list(x)
while(!is.null(x)) {
  x <- combine_parts(x, list(mat = M, sku = as.matrix(A$sku)))
  res <- c(res, list(x))
}

#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$mat
#>       p1_prop p2_prop p3_prop p4_prop p5_prop p6_prop
#>  [1,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE
#>  [2,]    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
#>  [3,]    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE
#>  [4,]   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
#>  [5,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
#>  [6,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE
#>  [7,]    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE
#>  [8,]    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
#>  [9,]    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
#> [10,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
#> 
#> [[1]]$sku
#>       [,1]
#>  [1,]    1
#>  [2,]    2
#>  [3,]    3
#>  [4,]    4
#>  [5,]    5
#>  [6,]    6
#>  [7,]    7
#>  [8,]    8
#>  [9,]    9
#> [10,]   10
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$mat
#>    p1_prop p2_prop p3_prop p4_prop p5_prop p6_prop
#> 1     TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE
#> 2    FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
#> 3    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
#> 4     TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
#> 5     TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE
#> 6     TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE
#> 7     TRUE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE
#> 8     TRUE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
#> 9     TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE
#> 10    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
#> 11   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
#> 12    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE   FALSE
#> 13    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE
#> 14    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE
#> 
#> [[2]]$sku
#>       [,1] [,2]
#>  [1,]    1    2
#>  [2,]    1    4
#>  [3,]    1    5
#>  [4,]    2    5
#>  [5,]    2    6
#>  [6,]    4    8
#>  [7,]    5    8
#>  [8,]    6    8
#>  [9,]    5    9
#> [10,]    6    9
#> [11,]    1   10
#> [12,]    2   10
#> [13,]    8   10
#> [14,]    9   10
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]]$mat
#>   p1_prop p2_prop p3_prop p4_prop p5_prop p6_prop
#> 1    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
#> 2    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
#> 
#> [[3]]$sku
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2    5
#> [2,]    1    2   10
#> 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

---

*Note: the other conditions and computations are not implemented, since they'd clutter the solution, but they should be easy to add.*